# NoSuchMethodFoundException when including a REST API with multipart

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, jax-rs, multipart

I have a Payara server and run a Java EE web application via Intellij on it. I also want to include an API (I did not choose the REST service template, as I want the project to be a web application). I included the following in my `build.gradle`:

```
    implementation group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-multipart-provider', version: '6.2.5.Final'
    compileOnly group: 'jakarta.platform', name: 'jakarta.jakartaee-web-api', version: '10.0.0'
    implementation group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-spring-boot-bom', version: '6.0.4.Final'
    implementation group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'javax.ws.rs-api', version: '2.1.1'
```

I get this error when I deploy my project:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.JaxrsServerFormUrlEncodedProvider class.
> at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:168)
> at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getConstructor(Utilities.java:157)
> at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:1043)
> at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:984)
> at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:974)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.create(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:194)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.create(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:30)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.AbstractCdiBeanSupplier.produce(AbstractCdiBeanSupplier.java:118)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.AbstractCdiBeanSupplier.access$000(AbstractCdiBeanSupplier.java:45)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.AbstractCdiBeanSupplier$2.getInstance(AbstractCdiBeanSupplier.java:88)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.AbstractCdiBeanSupplier._provide(AbstractCdiBeanSupplier.java:124)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.GenericCdiBeanSupplier.get(GenericCdiBeanSupplier.java:42)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.InstanceSupplierFactoryBridge.provide(InstanceSupplierFactoryBridge.java:53)
> at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.FactoryCreator.create(FactoryCreator.java:129)
> at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:466)
> at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:46)
> at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2103)
> at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
> at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)

I tried differernt versions of the libraries. It seems to compile when I have the same `build.gradle` for a REST service project. I want to include the API in my web application.

Comment: You have both Jersey and RESTEasy dependencies. The stack trace is showing Jersey calls. But the dependencies you are showing are RESTEasy. Pick one and get rid of the all the dependencies for the other